# Powershell script to schedule daily task error

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have a very simple power shell script that will register console applications as daily scheduled tasks.

```
$TaskCommand = Read-Host 'Enter the path to the console application'
$TaskName = "TaskName"
$TaskStartTime = "10PM"
$TaskArg = "-WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Executionpolicy unrestricted"

$TaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$TaskCommand" -Argument "$TaskArg"
$TaskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At $TaskStartTime -Daily
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $TaskAction -Trigger $TaskTrigger -TaskName "$TaskName" -User %computername%\theusername -Password "password" -RunLevel Highest
```

The application reads the file path from user input and attempts to register the application as a task using a specific user account. I can get the script working by using

```
-User "System"
```

However when I try to use the above script I get this error:

> Register-ScheduledTask: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

I have ensured that the account exists as it is currently running several services. I am also new to powershell so have tried adding quotations around the username with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't think PowerShell recognises `%computername%`. [Have a look at environment variables here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)

`$env:USERNAME`, `$env:USERDOMAIN` `$env:COMPUTERNAME` look relevant to your task.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was an issue of having trailing spaces where the variables were stored. Unrelated to the question at hand, but perhaps a sanity-check worth pursuing for others who reads this.

Comment: (If you want not to receive votes on an answer, edit it and set it to Community Wiki).